# repaint() function - JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem when i'm trying to use a Timer Object and a repaint() when it is called.

Here's my Window Class :

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Window extends JFrame{


    Panel pan = new Panel();
    JPanel container, north,south, west;
    JButton ip,print,cancel,ok;
    JTextArea timeStep;
    JLabel legend;
    double temperature=0.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();

    }

    public Window()
    {
        System.out.println("je suis là");
        this.setSize(700,400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Assignment2 - CPU temperature");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        north = new JPanel();
        ip = new JButton ("New");
        north.add(ip);
        north.add(new JLabel("Time Step: "));
        timeStep = new JTextArea("10",1,5);
        north.add(timeStep);
        print = new JButton ("Print");
        north.add(print);

        south = new JPanel();
        legend = new JLabel("Legends are here");
        south.add(legend);

        west = new JPanel();
        JLabel temp = new JLabel("°C");
        west.add(temp);

        container.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);
        container.add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setContentPane(container);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And Here's my Panel class :

```
 import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer chrono = new Timer(1000,this);
    int i = 0;
    int t = 10;

    public Panel()
    {

        super();
        chrono.start();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawLine(20, 20, 20, this.getHeight()-50);
        g.drawLine(20, this.getHeight()-50, this.getWidth()-50, this.getHeight()-50);
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 15, 35);
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 25, 35);
        g.drawLine(this.getWidth()-50, this.getHeight()-50, this.getWidth()-65, this.getHeight()-45);
        g.drawLine(this.getWidth()-50, this.getHeight()-50, this.getWidth()-65, this.getHeight()-55);
        g.drawLine(20+t, this.getHeight()-50-i, 20+t, this.getHeight()-50);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /*i = (int)(50+(20 + (Math.random() * (60 - 20))));
        t = t+10;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("chrono");*/
    }

}
```

Here's how it is like when the repaint() function isn't called :

GUI:

[image]

And Finally here's how it looks like when repaint() function is called :

GUI bug:

[image]

It seems that all of my JPanels are repainting only once and then everything works...

Any thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you never paint over what's drawn before. `JPanel` by default is supposed to be opaque, meaning that it will draw over its entire area each redraw, freeing the frame to not have to worry about cleaning up that space. However, you're removing that functionality from the `JPanel`.

In your `paintComponent` method, add this at the top:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

This will let the `JPanel` correctly redraw itself (by calling its own `paintComponent` method), so that you can do your drawing over a clean slate.

In response to your comment, the best way to keep the old lines is to keep track of each line to draw, and repaint them all each time. To do that, you would need to replace `t` and `i` with lists, which would look something like this:

```
List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> ts = new ArrayList<>();
int lastT = 0;
```

And then add to those instead of simply setting the value:

```
int i = (int)(50 + (20 + (Math.random() * (60 - 20))));
lastT += 10;
is.add(i);
ts.add(lastT);
repaint();
```

And finally, loop over each value:

```
for(int j = 0; i < is.size() && ts.size(); i++){
    int i = is.get(j);
    int t = ts.get(j);
    g.drawLine(20 + t, this.getHeight() - 50 - i,
               20 + t, this.getHeight() - 50);
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, so it may have some mistakes, but it should be the right idea.

Comment: Hello resuman,
Thank you very much for your quick answer ! It works perfectely but i need that the lines drawn every time the event is called stay printed ! And, here, it erases it and redraws it every time? Would have a solution for this ?
Thank you so much !

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud The best way to do that is to keep track of each line (eg. in a `List`) and redraw them each time. Trying to paint over what's already there will cause a **lot** of problems. If you don't care about resizing though, you could paint to a `BufferedImage`s `Graphics`, (which doesn't have the same problems), and simply draw that `Image` inside the repaint. I'll add an example of how these could work to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll stock the lines in a List !

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY. Thanks a million ! :)

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud Great, glad you got your solution :D